# jQuery trigger function on load no working

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery that triggers a function on keyup.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#calc").on("keyup", "input[type='text']", function() {
  calculateSum(this);
  });
calculateSum();
});
```

function calculateSum found here: http://jsfiddle.net/pmetzger/ANp8u/2/

If I load a value into the input field as a default value, obviously the calculateSum will not trigger because it's not a keyup.

I do though, need to be able to load a default value into the input fields at times and I need the calculateSum function to trigger on load in case there is a value that needs calculating. I have added the calculateSum() function at the end of my document.ready but it will only load the global sub-total. I need it to run as if I'm keying up in the value field. I also tried triggering the event, but no luck there as well.

I have put some default values in there for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this to trigger the bind event on the first element, you don't need to trigger it on all elements because then it will be run X elements.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#calc").on("keyup", "input[type='text']", function() {
     calculateSum(this);
  });
  $("input[type='text']").trigger("keyup");
});
```

Comment: Ok, so this helped for sure. I was able to just remove the :first and it triggered for everything in the table. Which was what I was hoping for. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var $elem = $('input[type="text"]', "#calc");

$elem.each(function($input) {
    if($input.val()) {
       $input.trigger('keyup');
    }
});
```

Comment: thats not the actual input though. thats a wrapper around the inputs

Comment: `$("#calc", 'input[type="text"]')` says find every `#calc` inside of `'input[type="text"]'`, which obviously will be 0 elements since inputs can't contain elements.

Comment: Fixed it.. Wrote it the other way round.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to either call trigger on the inputs or run the function on them manually like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Bind the event
  $("#calc").on("keyup", "input[type='text']", function() {
    calculateSum(this);
  }).find("input[type='text']").each(function() {
      calculateSum(this);
  });
});
```